# Unity GameObject.Find() not working in batchmode?

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I am trying to make GameObject.Find() work in batchmode but for some reason it returns a null object.

my code:

```
public class test: Monobehaviour {
    public static GameObject go;

    static void doing()
    {
        go = GameObject.Find ("testing");
    }
}
//testing is the name of the gameobject in the editor
```

I call it from the console on mac using: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -projectPath "" -executeMethod test.doing

Answer (score 1):

When running in batchmode, Unity does not load the scene you normally see when opening the project in the editor. Thus, there are no `GameObjects` to find.

If you add `using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;`, you can use the SceneManager to open your scene, then continue as expected.

Assuming your scene file is under `Assets/Scenes` and named `Main`, and includes an object named `TestObject`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

public class BatchTest : MonoBehaviour {
  static void runTest() {
    EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/Scenes/Main.unity");
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("TestObject");
    ...
  }
}
```

To run this in batchmode, similar to your example, I run:
`/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -projectPath "/path/to/project" -executeMethod BatchTest.runTest -logfile`

(`-logfile` with no specified logfile will output to console on Linux/Mac)